# Can't switch back to Windows host from remote Linux session

Tags: freerdp

host: Windows 10

remote: archlinux

1) wfreerdp --version
This is FreeRDP version 2.0.0-dev5 (d96a61d8c)

2) wfreerdp.exe /v:... /u:... /p:... /floatbar /f

Remote session works fine, but I can't switch to Windows host.

1) No float toolbar visible

2) Right Ctrl does not work

3) Ctrl+Alt+Enter does not work

4) Ctrl+Alt+Del is work. I can kill wfreerdp. But CAD is sent to archlinux, and KDE session is closed.

What would I expect:

1) Right Ctrl switch focus to windows host.

2) Ctrl+Alt+Enter toggle fullscreen

3) Floatbar is visible and operable (minimize, close, pin/unpin)

4) Ctrl+Alt+Del does not sent to remote session

Is it possible to setup that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Never version fix "floatbar".
See https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/5770